# Using the ddply comand on a subset of data

Tags: r, plyr

I got some issues using the command 'ddply' of the 'plyr' package. I created a dataframe which looks like this one :

```
           u      v intensity season
24986  -1.97  -0.35       2.0      1
24987  -1.29  -1.53       2.0      1
24988  -0.94  -0.34       1.0      1
24989  -1.03   2.82       3.0      1
24990   1.37   3.76       4.0      1
24991   1.93   2.30       3.0      2
24992   3.83  -3.21       5.0      2
24993   0.52  -2.95       3.0      2
24994   3.06  -2.57       4.0      2
24995   2.57  -3.06       4.0      2
24996   0.34  -0.94       1.0      2
24997   0.87   4.92       5.0      3
24998   0.69   3.94       4.0      3
24999   4.60   3.86       6.0      3
```

I tried to use the function cumsum on the u and v values, but I don't get what I want. When I select a subset of my data, corresponding to a season, for example :

```
x <- cumsum(mydata$u[56297:56704]*10.8)
y <- cumsum(mydata$v[56297:56704]*10.8)
```

...this works perfectly. The thing is that I got a huge dataset (67208 rows) with 92 seasons, and I'd like to make this function work on subsets of data. So I tried this :

```
new <- ddply(mydata, .(mydata$seasons), summarize, x=c(0,cumsum(mydata$u*10.8)))
```

...and the result looks like this :

```
24986              1             NA
24987              1             NA
24988              1             NA
```

I found some questions related to this one on stackoverflow and other website, but none of them helped me dealing with my problem. If someone has an idea, you're welcome ;)

Comment: don't use your data.frame's name inside the plyr "function".  just reference the column name as though it was defined:  `ddply(mydata, .(seasons), summarise, x=c(0, cumsum(u*10.8)))`.

Comment: OK, I feel so ashamed now... Thank you very much for your time, see ya around !

Comment: @Justin, please post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker done, bad habit!

Comment: @Justing: I often do quick answers within comments as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use your `data.frame's` name inside the `plyr` "function". just reference the column name as though it was defined:

`ddply(mydata, .(seasons), summarise, x=c(0, cumsum(u*10.8)))`